# Using Selenium, loop click on a link till new page appears

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I recently started using the Selenium module and have faced a hurdle that I was hoping would get cleared.

I made automation that clicks a link in a loop. The link has a 70% chance of doing nothing and a 30% chance of opening a new page. I wanted to make it so that the automation stops the looping process once the new page appears and clicks another link on that new page.

What I have so far:

```
# Searching for the link.
    link = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'css_selector'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(link)
    # Looping the click.
    for i in range(500):
        while True:
            try:
                linkclick = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css_selector')
                linkclick.click()
            except
                newlink = EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'new_css_selector'))
                WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(newlink)
                newlinkclick = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('new_css_selector')
                newlinkclick.click()
```

Comment: You'd have to check driver handles to see if it has that new opened url and then switch handles.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I just noticed that the new link is in an iframe so I had to change things up a bit.